# Using Autocomplete within WordPress causes some errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, autocomplete

I'm currently trying to add an Autocomplete to an input on my page which should dynamically return the search results when I start typing. Basically, everything works but I'm getting an error on the frontend and no results are displayed:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'suggestions' of null
    at t.processResponse (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:1)
    at i (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at x (jquery.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.js:4)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at t.verifySuggestionsFormat (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:1)
    at t.processResponse (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (jquery.autocomplete.min.js:1)
    at i (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at x (jquery.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.c (jquery.js:4)
```

This is my JS function:

```
<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready( function () {
        let searchAutocompleteUrl = "<?= admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ?>?action=search_autocomplete";
        jQuery( 'input[type=search]' ).devbridgeAutocomplete( {
            serviceUrl: searchAutocompleteUrl,
            minLength: 3
        } );
    } );
</script>
```

And this my PHP function:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_search_autocomplete', 'search_autocomplete' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_search_autocomplete', 'search_autocomplete' );
function search_autocomplete() {

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
    );

    $products = new WP_Query( $args );
    $items    = array();

    if ( $products !== null ) {
        foreach ( $products->posts as $result ) {
            $items[] = $result->post_title;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode( $items );
    wp_die();
}
```

This is the received result via when I start typing:

```
["dsdfsduzfgsdufzgsdfuzgsuzgfuszgdfuzgsdf","sdfsdfusfiusuzsuzsfuzgfuzgsduzgusdzgf","Ich bin ein Hund"]
```

Do you have any ideas how I can get this done?

Comment: more info needed, need to specify which particular line that error is pointing to or add full stack if available, do you get that error on page load or when you do something like clicking a button or type in?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam as I wrote in my question, when I start typing. Maybe the result has the wrong format but I can't find a specific tutorial with a correct format.

Comment: hard to guess like this without a live link or reproduceable example as the error does not relate to any line of code provided above

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I've added the result which get's received via the function. I got it with calling the url directly in the browser.

Comment: https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/issues/440

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I had the wrong format. Got it now - basically. Now I need to find out how I can pass the current input so that I can only return for example results that are having this specific word or string concatination in it you know?

Comment: have you fixed both of the errors above ?

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Yes!

Comment: then add a separate question and provide the relevant info there along with the response format that you are sending back from the server